# Pushing deeply nested arrays into Object properties and keys

Tags: javascript

```
function transformEmployeeData(employeeData) {
  var myObj = {};
  var myKeys = [];
  var myValues = [];

  for(var i=0; i < employeeData.length; i++) {
    for(var y=0; y<employeeData[i].length; y++) {
      for(var q=0; q< employeeData[i][y].length; q+=2) {      
        myKeys.push(employeeData[i][y][q]);    
      }
    }
  }

  for(var i=0; i < employeeData.length; i++) {
    for(var y=0; y<employeeData[i].length; y++) {
      for(var q=0; q< employeeData[i][y].length; q+=2) {      
        myValues.push(employeeData[i][y][q]);    
      }
    }
  }



  return myValues;
}

transformEmployeeData([
    [
        ['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']
    ],
    [
        ['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']
    ]
]);



/*
Output should look something like..

[
    {firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Blow', age: 42, role: 'clerk'},
    {firstName: 'Mary', lastName: 'Jenkins', age: 36, role: 'manager'}
]
*/
```

I'm attempting to push the correct data into myKeys and myValues. That way I can assign those as object keys and values. However, I can't figure out how to do it, I am using q+=2 and failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function transformEmployeeData(employeeData) {
  var myValues = [];

  for(var i=0; i < employeeData.length; i++) {
    myValues.push(Object.fromEntries(employeeData[i]))
  }
  return myValues;
}
```

Comment: No, a loop is unnecessary, use `Object.fromEntries`

Comment: Yeah, the second loop could be replaced by Object.fromEntries

Answer (score 1):

It is possible **without** a loop. In this situation I would use the following:

```
function transformEmployeeData(employeeData) {
 return Object.fromEntries(employeeData.flat());
}
```

Example:

```js
function transformEmployeeData(employeeData) {
 return Object.fromEntries(employeeData.flat());
}

let data = transformEmployeeData([
    [
        ['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']
    ],
    [
        ['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']
    ]
]);
console.log(data)
```

Just be careful, this will only unnest one level.

Comment: There will be duplicate keys when array is flattened

Comment: I don't see any duplicates

Comment: If there are duplicates just put it in a `new Set` then revert it to an Object to remove the duplicates.

Comment: I mean the first object with name: 'Joe' will be lost. Refer the desired output

Comment: Oh, I see. Then the OP will have to adjust the function to suit their needs.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something a little more simple and loop over your starting arrays and use their indexes to keep the insertions straight.

```js
const oldFormat = [
    [
        ['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']
    ],
    [
        ['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']
    ]
];

let newFormat = [];

for (let index = 0; index < oldFormat.length; index++) {
  newFormat[index] = {}
  for(attribute in oldFormat[index]) {
      newFormat[index][oldFormat[index][attribute][0]] = oldFormat[index][attribute][1];
    }
}

console.log(newFormat);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Map object from your Key/Value arrays and then use .map to format as you like.

```js
var arr = [[['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']],[['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']]]

var outputArr = arr.map(element =>{
  return Object.fromEntries(new Map(element));
}) 
        
console.log(outputArr)
```